# How do i avoid error in the if condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors

```
function changeBGG1() {
     var a = $('#vbox').css("backgroundColor");
     if (a == "#800000") {
         $('#vbox').css("webkitAnimation", 'Red2Green 2s');
         $('#vbox').css("backgroundColor", '#004C00');
     }
 }
```

i know that there is an error in the condition check, but i dnt know how to avoid it as there is no method to parse  a color.

Comment: You should set animation using a class and check for that class instead

Comment: jquery has no function to parse the color hex format.

Comment: Even if it has, you shouldn't check for a CSS property, instead redefine your logic to use a class and check it using e.g `if($('#vbox').hasClass('xxxx'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS, background colours are generally returned in `rgb(...)` format, *but not always*. If there's transparency involved, it'll be `rgba(...)` format. Some browsers (especially older ones) will use `#RRGGBB` format.

Long story short, you *cannot* rely on the value of `backgroundColor` for any kind of comparison.

Use a `.data()` property instead.

Comment: @user3648908 I think this answer's elaboration is ***much more*** than the elaboration of your question.

Comment: @KingKing Well said !

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
$.fn.getHexBackgroundColor = function() {
    var rgb = $(this).css('background-color');
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    function hex(x) {return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);}
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}


function changeBGG1() {
     var a = $('#vbox').getHexBackgroundColor();
     if (a == "#800000") {
         $('#vbox').css("webkitAnimation", 'Red2Green 2s');
         $('#vbox').css("backgroundColor", '#004C00');
     }
 }
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined  **line 1**

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  **8th line**

Comment: link/import jquery before any other javascript

Comment: @user3648908 Dont put this code on *line1* , just place this after jquery script tag

Answer (score 0):

```
var rgbString = "rgb(0, 70, 255)"; // get this in whatever way.

var parts = rgbString.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
// parts now should be ["rgb(0, 70, 255", "0", "70", "255"]

delete (parts[0]);
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
    if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
} 
var hexString ='#'+parts.join('').toUpperCase();
```

By this method an rgb color can be converted to a sting in hex form and be compared normally like a string in javascript.